# How does Flink barriers work with Kafka Partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Assume that we have a single Flink job which consumes from a single kafka topic, deserialises the message and sinks the message to a logger.

The [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/concepts/stateful-stream-processing/#checkpointing) does not say how and when barriers are injected into the data stream however let's assume that they are chosen after some predefined interval.

Now things get unclear. Imagine a record with partition 1 and offset 99 was just consumed by TM-1 (Task Manager) and a record with partition 2 and offset 67 was just consumed by TM-2. How does injecting a barrier help?

Why doesn't the individual TMs just inform JM of it's last read kafka partition, offset and valueState etc? Put other ways, to understand barriers I'm asking what will be the unsolved problems or tradeoffs if barriers didn't exist?